# Histogram with Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, dataframe, histogram

I have a dataframe df_Ratio with this structure

```
class_energy ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F1 ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F3 ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F5 ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F6 ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F7 ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F8
high 0.166667 0.166667 0.166667 0.166667 0.166667 0.166667 
low 0.166964 0.167003 0.167081 0.166935 0.166058 0.165961 
medium 0.167268 0.167400 0.167165 0.167334 0.165224 0.165609
```

I need to create a histogram concerning only **high** rows :

In the x axis `ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F5 ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F6 ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F7 ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F8`

and the y axis represents the values : `"0.166667 0.166667 0.166667 0.166667 0.166667 0.166667 "`

Any idea please?

Comment: What have you tried? Are you sure you want a histogram and not a bar chart?

Comment: @DavidG I think in this case, it's better to use  bar chart. Thank you . Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I got everything right, but here is a working example:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.read_csv('data.txt', sep=' ')
df = df.T         # transpose dataframe

plt.bar(range(len(df.high)-1), df.high[1:], align='center')
plt.xticks(range(len(df.high)-1), df.index[1:], size='small')
plt.xticks(rotation=90)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Probably you have to adjust the data range by `[1:]`, depending on how exactly your data looks and on what you want to plot.

Comment: This example make things more complicated, thank you anyway

Comment: Can you criticize more constructively, please? It took me some time to do it... What is the problem?